# Muting mouse click on specific part of tablet screen

Tags: windows, mouse, touchscreen, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

My surface tablet has broken screen.

It just automatically clicks a very specific part of the screen.

So I can't use it because mouse cursor goes to that part with frequency higher than 1 click per second.

I can't just ask MS to fix it.

So if there is a program that "mutes" a specific mouse click on some specific part of the screen, it will almost nearlu fix the problem.

Is there such a program? Or is it possible to code it?

Comment: Get the screen repaired.

Comment: @DavidPostill    Means.. there is no possible solution?

Comment: I cannot be certain, but I would be very surprised if there was. It is a touch screen device correct? It sounds like you have a short circuit on that part of the screen. Is it physically damaged?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes it is physically damaged. Some slight crack line is on the screen and the repeat-click point is there.

Comment: Then you need to replace the screen as I said before.